# Error al intentar abrir un archivo en zig

Tags: filesystem

estoy intentando abrir un archivo en el lenguaje de programación Zig, pero por alguna razón recibo un error. He estado investigando he intentando entender por qué esto no esta funcionando, pero no he encontrado mucha información al respecto.

Código:

```
const std = @import("std");

const fs = std.fs;

pub fn main() !void {
    const file = try fs.openFileAbsolute("/home/user/Code/code/agenda/index.txt", fs.File.OpenFlags{ .mode = .read_only });
    var buffer: []u8 = undefined;
    var bytes_read = try file.read(buffer);
    const writer = std.io.getStdOut().writer();
    if (bytes_read < 0) {
        try writer.print("Something went wrong!");
    } else {
        var data = buffer[0..bytes_read];
        try writer.print("{s}", .{data});
        bytes_read = try file.read(buffer);
    }

    defer file.close();
}
```

El error que estoy obteniendo es el siguiente:

```
thread 24066 panic: reached unreachable code
/snap/zig/6352/lib/std/os.zig:706:23: 0x2129c5 in read (index)
            .FAULT => unreachable,
                      ^
/snap/zig/6352/lib/std/fs/file.zig:974:32: 0x21030a in read (index)
            return os.read(self.handle, buffer);
                               ^
./index.zig:8:35: 0x20ffb4 in main (index)
    var bytes_read = try file.read(buffer);
                                  ^
/snap/zig/6352/lib/std/start.zig:614:37: 0x20f955 in posixCallMainAndExit (index)
            const result = root.main() catch |err| {
                                    ^
/snap/zig/6352/lib/std/start.zig:376:5: 0x20f411 in _start (index)
    @call(.{ .modifier = .never_inline }, posixCallMainAndExit, .{});
    ^
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: El error que estás recibiendo indica que se ha alcanzado un código inalcanzable, lo que sugiere que hay un problema en el código que estás utilizando. Asegurate de que el archivo que estás intentando abrir exista en la ubicación especificada (repetando mayuscula y minusculas) y que tengas los permisos necesarios para acceder a él. También puedes considerar utilizar una biblioteca de manejo de archivos para simplificar el proceso. En caso de que el archivo exista en la ubicacion que especificas y otorges permisos a el y el problema aun persiste, comparte un poco mas sobre tu error. Saludos :3